# If 10 notifications come through at once only vibrate once and say you have 10 notifications from [appname] with the app logo showing

Tags: android

Creating an app in which i am showing  notification when new feed added.So for this i am using service which will run in background and
add the data in sqlitedatabase.But for this i did not create new service and use already existing service in my app fusedlocation service to call server and add data in sqlitedatabasehere created method to show notification,in which i show title of notification and set content text and it's working perfactly .now i want that if one feed added notification should show one feed received and when 10 feed added it should show 10 feed received.
how to do that?

In fusedService in onLocationChanged call this

```
 long last_time=//getting value from preference
            Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
            long current_time=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            double difference=24*60*60;

            if((current_time-last_time)>difference){
                getFeeds();//calling server in this
            }
```

Use this method to show notification

```
public void processStartNotification() {
    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(locationActivity);
    builder.setContentTitle("New Item Received")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(title)//coming from server
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo);

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context,Activity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            NOTIFICATION_ID,
            mainIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    PreferenceClass.setBooleanPreference(locationActivity,Constant.NOTIFICATION,true);
    final NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.locationActivity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: use notification id is static value

Comment: you changed line "manager.notify(0, builder.build());"

Comment: or set NOTIFICATION_ID=0;

Comment: where to increase this static value

Comment: use sqlite database for store notify id